# What is the easiest way to earn a few more Dromund Kaas commendations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So actually I've just got my eye on a piece of Dromund Kaas commendation gear that I am 1 commendation shy of affording. What are my options for getting that missing commendation? Is there a "daily" I can run (not the L50 dailies, I only just got my spaceship.) Some other way? For the future, if I need more then one, do I have options (and what?)

Comment: As a rule of thumb for future reference: all Heroic quests are repeatable daily, and they all yield commendations.

Comment: Commendations are also possible as loot on specific factions on the planet in question. So besides doing heroics, you might chance upon one when defeating certain enemies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dromund Kas has a couple options:

- [Friends of Old](http://www.torhead.com/mission/2KQ4T04/friends-of-old) west of Kaas City Expansion District

Requires a group of 4, impossible to solo "at-level". Pretty long, as heroics go, and may take some time to get a group.

- [Shadow Spawn](http://www.torhead.com/mission/5DDTNl2/shadow-spawn) east of Lord Grathan's Estate

Intended for a group of 2, but unless you've got CC or a healer, you might have trouble with some of the exterior pulls. Generally easier to get groups for, though.

- [Saving Face](http://www.torhead.com/mission/fr1tEua/saving-face) below the bridge leading to the Unfinished Colossus

Another group of 2 quest. I was able to solo it as a sorc. (Self-heal + kite Woo!)

- [Personal Challenge](http://www.torhead.com/mission/fudXv9a/personal-challenge) due west of Dromund Kaas spaceport.

Group of 2, and lowest level daily quest on the planet. Should be solo-able at your level.

Comment: There's also the AREA[4] quest, Hadra's Defeat.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Does that reward commendations though? I'm inclined to think it doesn't, though I don't know why.

Comment: I *thoughr* it did, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Anecdotally, the rewards for Hadra's Defeat are just [XP and credits](http://www.torhead.com/mission/6GcdKmF/hadras-defeat#comments).

Answer (score 2):

An additional option is to run the Flashpoint associated with a particular planet and it's commendations. In the case of DK, that's Black Talon and Athiss.

As a bonus, by the time you're leaving DK, if you're a healing capable class with a tank companion (Operative, Sorc), or a tank capable class with a healing companion (Powertech), BT should be a joke to solo, and it shouldn't be terribly hard for anyone else either with some CC and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Quest chains will still award commendations upon completion, you can visit the major hubs to see if you are missing any and complete them.

Commendations have a chance to drop off random mobs in the zone. You could gather up a bunch of the lower level normal mobs and do some area of effect damage and kill a lot of them quickly. Although this method isn't guaranteed to give you commendations and is luck based.

Comment: In this case, it sounds like @aslum is looking to eke out a few extra commendations at level - not doubling back as an overpowered high level after a cosmetic item.

Comment: Fair enough, wasn't really able to gather that from the context of the question. I blame late night answering :P

Answer (score 0):

The daily flash point missions available on the Republic/Imperial space stations also give commendations for particular planets based on the level of the flash point.  Running Hammer Station to complete the Emerging Conflicts I daily mission might give Dromund Kaas commendations.